# Make a HTTP Post call within Azure Functions using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to make a HTTP Post call from within Azure Functions using nodejs. The payload which needs to be passed is in JSON with two properties title and description.  For some reason, the below code doesn't work and I don't get any errors in the log too. The POST operation works in a Postman rest client. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

```js
var http = require('https');
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    var body = {
        "title": "Sunday", 
        "description": "Last day of the week"
    }
    const options = {
        hostname: 'capservice-xxxxxxxx.ondemand.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/incident/SafetyIncidents',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': body.length
        }
    }

    var response = '';
    const request = http.request(options, (res) => {
        context.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

        res.on('data', (d) => {
            response += d;
        })

        res.on('end', (d) => {
            context.res = {
                body: response
            }
           context.done();
        })
    })

    request.on('error', (error) => {
        context.log.error(error)
        context.done();
    })

    request.write(body);
    request.end();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a bit more chance to investigate the issue. I've actually tested it on Azure Functions now - and got it to work.

Your `body` variable is incorrectly typed:

```js
// This assumes that the body type is JSON.
var body = {
   "title": "Sunday", 
   "description": "Last day of the week"
}
```

See the reference here: https://nodejs.dev/learn/make-an-http-post-request-using-nodejs

> ```
> const https = require('https')
> // See the JSON.stringify
> const data = JSON.stringify({
>   todo: 'Buy the milk'
> })
> ```

When I try to execute your function above as it is (with changing the URL) - I'm receiving a parameter error as below

> FailureException: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument
> must be of type **string** or an **instance of Buffer**. Received an instance
> of **ObjectStack**

Adding the `JSON.stringify` to the body object solved the problem for me.

Comment: But my post call is for a https endpoint. The URL which I am posting to is https://capservice-db-srv-boring-roan-sb.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com/incident/SafetyIncidents. If you access the URL on a browser, you will be able to see the records. I am trying to add entries to it via the Azure Function

Comment: I tried renaming some of those variable. Still no luck 
Can you please try using the POST request to the API mentioned in this webiste to see if you can get it to work https://attacomsian.com/blog/node-http-requests-using-request-module